# Inverting op-amp does not give expected result

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am using this op-amp [LMC6482](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc6484.pdf) and trying to invert the input. In the diagram below I show how I have wired it up. With this wiring I expect to have an output of 5V (supply is 5v. But just get floating around .75v if input is grounded or 5v.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opamp is trying to invert your signal, meaning that it will try to change the sign.  If your resistors are the same value, then you have

```
gain = -R/R = -1
```

If you put 2.5V into the input of the circuit, then your opamp is trying to

```
Voutput = gain * Vinput
Voutput = -1 * 2.5V
Voutput = -2.5V
```

Since the opamp cannot go to -2.5, it gets as close as it can at 0.75V, saturating there.  The same is true for your entire range of 0V to 5V.  The circuit will try to drive the output from 0V to -5V, but will only go as low as it can until saturation.

Based on your comments, I suspect that you are trying to implement:

```
Vout = 5V - Vin
```

In this case, you want to implement a [differential amplifier](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html) with one end tied to +5V and with the gain of 1.

Comment: oh, so the goal is to get the opposite result. i.e 5v=0 2.5=2.5 and 0v=5v.

Comment: Not quite.  Imagine simply multiplying by -1:

Comment: 0Vin yields 0Vout, 5Vin yields -5Vout

Comment: the required result can be achieved with a non-inverting circuit?

Comment: @maxum I am not sure what 'the required result' is.  Given an input range of 0V to 5V, what do you want the output to do?

Comment: I revised the answer a bit.  I believe that you are looking for a differential amplifier configuration or 'subtractor'

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a positive DC offset to the amplifier, otherwise the opamp will try to output a *negative* voltage for any nonzero input voltage. Since the opamp lacks a negative supply voltage, it just outputs the minimum possible voltage all the time.

If you want 0 V to become 5 V and 5 V to become 0 V, you need a gain factor of 1 and a DC offset of 5 V.
In order to have a gain of 1, both resistors (Rin and Rf) must be equal in value, and in order to have a DC offset of 5 V you need a "virtual ground" of 5/2 V (you need to keep the non inverting input at 2.5 V instead of grounding it).

Comment: in the example rf and rin are the same. If I put a voltage divider on the non-inverting input I will get the result?

Comment: @Maxum Yes a voltage divider can be used for producing the virtual ground potential. I would add a 100 nF capacitor from the non inverting input to the (real) ground for reducing noise.

Comment: So proposed solution would look like this? http://goo.gl/BbEqpU

Comment: I like this solution as well, up-voted :)

Comment: @slightlynybbled To be honest it's pretty much the same as yours, an inverting amplifier with a virtual ground produced with a voltage divider is exactly equivalent to a differential amplifier. I just didn't notice that you had already answered before posting.

Comment: @jms You are correct, of course, and I love the two different approaches arriving at the same answer.  I upvoted your answer and your comment b/c they have value in this thread.